# flyway migration failing for update sql statement with join

Tags: spring-data-jpa, microservices, flyway

I created the update statement with joins in flywaydb with 8.x version. the update statement is below and the actual database is postgres 14.x. It is showing syntax error.

**SQL Query :**

> update ss s set s_name = csc.name from  c_s_category csc where csc.uid
> = s.fk_csc_id and s.fk_csc_id is not null;

Can you please suggest, how can i proceed further with flyway script migration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the UPDATE statement after any other statement, try to move the UPDATE to its own migration file.